# How do I refer to an uninstantiated class in Scala?

Tags: class, scala, types

The fact that you can do the following in Scala is pretty neat:

```
scala> class FooBar
defined class FooBar

scala> val a = new FooBar
a: FooBar = FooBar@7efeedca

scala> val the_class = a.getClass
the_class: java.lang.Class[_ <: FooBar] = class FooBar

scala> val b = the_class.newInstance
b: FooBar = FooBar@1ef1df56
```

Suppose I want to set the value of `the_class` directly.  I appear to be able to declare a variable of the correct type:

```
scala> var the_class: java.lang.Class[_ <: FooBar] = null
the_class: java.lang.Class[_ <: FooBar] = null
```

But I don't appear to be able to bind the variable to any value.  Is this possible?

```
scala> the_class = class FooBar
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       the_class = class FooBar
                   ^
scala> the_class = FooBar
<console>:9: error: not found: value FooBar
       the_class = FooBar
                   ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
val the_class = classOf[FooBar]
```

Comment: Yes! Don't know how I missed this. Thanks.